# How to enable domain administrator to run service syncthing before windows logon?

Tags: windows-server

In Windows Server 2022, I have a service, Log On is set to the administrator user, and the service runs when I run it manually, it just won't run automatically on startup (same for the task) before logging in. The account has all of the privileges I could find, it's an administrator account. In "Resultant Set of Policy" (rsop.msc) under "Log on as a service" I have "Administrators".

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact problem, but I can suggest to use the [Syncthing Windows Setup](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/SyncthingWindowsSetup/) installer I built and install the service. It has the advantage of creating a service account with limited permissions. (I would definitely not recommend running Syncthing as a service using a privileged account.)